# How would I get records from a table, with not matching IDs from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Firstly I would like to say that I am sorry if it is a duplicate, I really did not find anything that would help me. I am quite new to real SQL development, so if somebody could even point me to some resources I would very much appreciate it.

Problem:

I am not sure how to handle things, I suspect the need of `UNION` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Summary:

Table1: user1 history of viewed articles (1 column with article IDs)

Table2: user2 history of viewed articles (1 column with article IDs)

Table3: articles (more columns has IDs)

Now I would like an `UNION` between `user1` and `user2` history and get the IDs of articles that both have not seen yet limited to 10.

Pseudo code:

```
(SELECT * FROM user1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM user2) as UnionTable

SELECT top(10) * 
FROM article 
WHERE UnionTable.id <> article.id

OR

SELECT * FROM articles LEFT OUTER JOIN UnionTable
```

The expected outcome is a list of article IDs that are not found in the union table. Are there any other better ways? Subqueries or procedures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `UNION` result-set, but you can also do  :

```
WITH CTE AS (
     <UNION Query here>
)
SELECT TOP (10) a.*
FROM article a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE c WHERE c.ID = a.ID);
```

You can use `OUTER JOIN` with filtration :

```
SELECT TOP (10) a.*
FROM article a LEFT OUTER JOIN
     CTE c 
     ON c.id = a.id
WHERE c.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: +1 for the "where not exists"  If you check the execution plans for both, you'll likely find that where not exists is more efficient and pulls less data.

Comment: Thank you! I selected to be the correct answer because you also used 'with' and I did not know about it, while I really should have had...

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a subquery

```
select * from articles a
where a.id not in (
    select u.id from UnionTable u
)
```

but I prefer the left join

```
select * from articles a
left join UnionTable u on u.id=a.id
where u.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
SELECT TOP (10) a.*
FROM article a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user1 v WHERE v.ID = a.ID) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user2 v WHERE v.ID = a.ID) ;
```

This can make use of indexes on `user1(id)` and `user2(id)`.

More importantly, though, you should fix your data model.  You should have one table `userArticles` with information like this:

```
create table userArticles (
    userArticleId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    userId int references users(userId),
    articleId int references articles(articleId),
    viewDateTime datetime default getdate()
);
```

Spreading information such as views through multiple tables is a bad idea.